# Comparison of fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Range the following terms in order:$$ \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^{1/e}, \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{1/2e}, \left( \frac{1}{e} \right)^{1/2} $$

My attempt: Using the monotone function $ x^{2e} $, we raise the terms above to the $ 2e $-th power and get
$$ \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{e^e}. $$
So $ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{1/2e} $ is the largest. It only leaves to compare $ 9 $ and $ e^e $, then I am stuck. Can someone help me here? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ee

Comment: Are you allowed any tools such as logarithm tables, taylor series, approximations?  Without these, what properties do you have that you are allowed to use which can allow us to distinguish $e$ from another unknown constant?

Comment: @mfl surely that goes against the spirit of the problem, it appears to be a "determine via pen-and-paper approaches only" sort of problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz Nothing, but I think using the fact that $ 2.718<e<2.719 $ or the definition of $ e $ by $ \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x} $ is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $(2,5)^5 > 97$ (you can compute this by hand), so $(2,5)^{2,5} > \sqrt{97} > 9$.
And $e > 2,5$, so $e^e > 9$.

Answer (score 0):

I would use $e^e\gt (2.7^2)^{1.359}=7.29^{1.359}\gt 7.29^ {4/3} =7.29\cdot 7.29^{1/3}=7.29\cdot 9\cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac 1{100}}\gt 7.29 \cdot 9 \cdot \frac 15\gt 9$
just because I know $3^6=9^3=27^2=729$